# calling a separate method in an another one in Python

Tags: python, nameerror, scoping

I have multiple methods, that I don't know how to put together in Python 3.4. Eventually, this would be a library of methods and I am wrapping them in one class Estimators. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Estimators():
    """some methods for building basic estimators.
        All methods.
    """
    def average(series):
        return float(sum(series))/len(series)

    def moving_average(series, n):
        return self.average(series[-n:])
def main():
    series = [3, 10, 12, 13, 12, 10, 12]
    done = average(series)
    print(done)
    outputmv = moving_averge(series, 2)
    print('this is the moving average:\n %d.2' % outputmv)
```

It throws

```
`NameError: global name 'average' is not defined
```

Also, I want to make sure this is the right architecture. What is the good practice in Python to define multiple methods that would have (functional) dependencies all along? By functional dependencies I mean some methods might use methods defined outside their scope.

Comment: methods of a class are useful to refer to the class, you should better put these functions inside a separate module (another file *.py) and import them

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it seems better to use a [module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html) rather than a class. A module is basically just a separate python file. So if you name a file estimators.py and put your functions in them, you can import them from another file like so:

```
from estimators import average

series = [3, 10, 12, 13, 12, 10, 12]
done = average(series)
```

Edit to respond to comment:

If your estimators.py file looks like this, you should be to import your moving average function:

```
def average(series):
    return float(sum(series))/len(series)

def moving_average(series, n):
    return average(series[-n:])
```

Notice that I changed `self.average` to just `average`, since `self` refers to an instance of a class, and these functions are not in a class.

Comment: it is the moving_avergage that is causing problems since it calls average method: ImportError: cannot import name moving_averge

Comment: I've updated my answer. Have you gotten it working now?

Comment: yes it did. there was a typo that first bugged me when I tested it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What @user257297 says about staticmethods is correct, though you will also have to call the class first before calling that method. I would suggest two options:

The first one is to change your main to:

```
def main():
    series = [3, 10, 12, 13, 12, 10, 12]
    done = Estimators.average(series)
    print(done)
    outputmv = Estimators.moving_averge(series, 2)
    print('this is the moving average:\n %d.2' % outputmv)
```

and add @staticmethod to the method definition.
The other one is to modify your class and instantiate an object from Estimators and call the methods this way:

```
class Estimators():
    """some methods for building basic estimators.
        All methods.
    """
    def average(self, series):
        return float(sum(series))/len(series)

    def moving_average(self, series, n):
        return self.average(series[-n:])
```

and call them this way:

```
...    
estimators = Estimators()
estimators.average(series)
...
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: Estimators instance has no attribute 'moving_averge' when I call an instance of the class as you mentioned. The first average methods works fine though.

Comment: @office206 I'm glad it helped! Mark it as correct if you can :D

Comment: doesn't seem I have the permission to do so. @Agustin